# Changing a vector into an array makes my program slower

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, vector

I profiled a program of mine and found out that the very hotspot was `levenshtein_distance`, called recursively. I decided to try and optimize it.

```
lvh_distance levenshtein_distance( const std::string & s1, const std::string & s2 )
{
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    std::vector<unsigned int> col( len2+1 ), prevCol( len2+1 );

    const size_t prevColSize = prevCol.size();
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < prevColSize; i++ )
        prevCol[i] = i;

    for( unsigned int i = 0, j; i < len1; ++i )
    {
        col[0] = i+1;
        const char s1i = s1[i];
        for( j = 0; j < len2; ++j )
        {
            const auto minPrev = 1 + std::min( col[j], prevCol[1 + j] );
            col[j+1] = std::min( minPrev, prevCol[j] + ( static_cast<unsigned int>( s1i != s2[j] ) ) );
        }
        col.swap( prevCol );
    }
    return prevCol[len2];
}
```

**TL;DR:** I changed `std::string` → `std::array`

War Story:
And after running vtune on it, I found that the line that updates `col[j+1]` was the one slowing down everything (90% of the time spent on it). I thought: OK, maybe this is an aliasing problem, maybe the compiler cannot determine that the character arrays within the string objects are unaliased as they are masked by the string interface and spends 90% of his time checking that no other part of the program modified them.

So I changed my string into a static array, because there, there is no dynamic memory, and the next step would have been using `restrict` to help the compiler. But in the meantime, I decided to check if I had gained any performance by doing so.

```
lvh_distance levenshtein_distance( const std::string & s1, const std::string & s2 )
{
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    static constexpr unsigned MAX_STRING_SIZE = 512;
    assert(len1 < MAX_STRING_SIZE && len2 < MAX_STRING_SIZE);
    static std::array<unsigned int, MAX_STRING_SIZE> col, prevCol;

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < len2+1; ++i )
        prevCol[i] = i;

    // the rest is unchanged
}
```

**TL;DR**: now it runs slow.

What happened is that I lost performance. A lot. Instead of running in ~ 6 seconds, my sample program now runs in 44 seconds. Using vtune to profile again shows that a function is called over and over again: `std::swap` (for you, gcc folks, this is in bits/move.h), which is in turn called by `std::swap_ranges` (bits/stl_algobase.h).

I suppose that `std::min` is implemented using `quicksort`, which explains why there is swapping around, but I don’t understand why swapping, in that case, takes so much time.

**EDIT**: Compiler options: I am using gcc with options "-O2 -g -DNDEBUG" and a bunch of warning specifiers.

Comment: I would guess that if you swap `vector`s, you swap the pointers to the underlying arrays and if you swap `array`s, the arrays are copied using a temporary.

Comment: `min` should never be implemented by sorting, since finding the value by sequential scan is faster than any possible sorting algorithm!

Comment: @PaulR I added that in the question

Comment: @DanielFischer That's indeed a very good (and most probably the correct) answer already. Swapping vectors is a no-op, while swapping arrays should indeed most probably call `std::swap_ranges`.

Comment: @dionadar Even that is by far overkill in this case. That's good old two-argument `std::min` here, which is nothing else than a simple `(b<a) ? b : a`. So this being done by quicksort is even more unimaginable.

Comment: @ChristianRau True of course - however `(b<a) ? b : a` is a minimal example of sequential scan :)

Comment: @dionadar You mean a `std::min`imal example (Ok, I'll stop ;))

Comment: It's quite easy for lines to get conflated in optimized builds, are you sure that it's not this that is the actual bottleneck: `col.swap( prevCol );`. You should try having `std::array<...> *pCol, *pPrevCol;` pointing to the two real arrays, changing all of the accesses via pointers and swapping the pointers... or doing the outer loop two iterations at a time and manually swapping `col` and `prevCol` in the second half (you'll need an extra test and break between the two halves and the `return` statement will need a conditional of some sort).

Comment: @CharlesBailey Now maybe you will post a proper answer (since the `swap` is exactly the problem here). *Daniel Fischer* didn't after realizing the problem, too.

Comment: @CharlesBailey using Howard Hinnant's [stack allocator](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html) for `std::vector` combines the best of both worlds: pointer swapping and no dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an experiment I ran a version of your original code largely unmodified with a pair of short strings an got timings of ~36s for the array version and ~8s for the vector version.

Your version seems to depend very much on the choice of `MAX_STRING_SIZE`. When I used 50 instead of 512 (which just fitted my strings), the timing for the array version went down to about 16s.

I then performed this by-hand translation of your main loop to get rid of the explicit swap. This further reduced the time of the array version to 11s, and more interestingly, now made the array version timing independent of the choice of `MAX_STRING_SIZE`. When putting it back to 512, the array version still took 11s.

This is good evidence that the explicit swap of the arrays is where the bulk of the perfomance issue with your version was.

There is a still a significant difference between the array and the vector version with the array version talking around 40% longer. I haven't had a chance to investigate exactly why this might be.

```
for( unsigned int i = 0, j; i < len1; ++i )
{
    {
        col[0] = i+1;
        const char s1i = s1[i];
        for( j = 0; j < len2; ++j )
        {
            const auto minPrev = 1 + std::min( col[j], prevCol[1 + j] );
            col[j+1] = std::min( minPrev, prevCol[j] + ( static_cast<unsigned int>( s1i != s2[j] ) ) );
        }
    }

    if (!(++i < len1))
        return col[len2];

    {
        prevCol[0] = i+1;
        const char s1i = s1[i];
        for( j = 0; j < len2; ++j )
        {
            const auto minPrev = 1 + std::min( prevCol[j], col[1 + j] );
            prevCol[j+1] = std::min( minPrev, col[j] + ( static_cast<unsigned int>( s1i != s2[j] ) ) );
        }
    }
}
return prevCol[len2];
```

Answer (score 1):

First off: @DanielFischer has already in all probability pointed out what caused your performance degradation: Swapping `std::arrays` is a linear time operation, while swapping `std::vector` is a constant time operation. While some compilers may be able to optimize this away, your gcc seems unable to do so.

Also important: Utilizing a `static` array like you did here makes your code inherently not threadsafe. It is usually not a good idea.

Removing one of the arrays (or vectors) and the associated swap and using a dynamically allocated c-array is actually pretty easy and results in superior performance (at least for my setup).
A few more transformations (like consistently using `size_t`) results in the following function:

```
unsigned int levenshtein_distance3( const std::string & s1, const std::string & s2 )
{
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    ::std::unique_ptr<size_t[]> col(new size_t[len2 + 1]);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len2+1; ++i )
        col[i] = i;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len1; ++i )
    {
        size_t lastc = col[0];
        col[0] = i+1;
        const char s1i = s1[i];
        for(size_t j = 0; j < len2; ++j )
        {
            const auto minPrev = 1 + (::std::min)(col[j], col[j + 1]);
            const auto newc = (::std::min)(minPrev, lastc + (s1i != s2[j] ? 1 : 0));
            lastc = col[j+1];
            col[j + 1] = newc;
        }
    }
    return col[len2];
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<size_t[]> col(new size_t[len2 + 1]);` - Isn't this just a `std::vector`, though?

Comment: *"While some compilers may be able to optimize this away, your gcc seems unable to do so."* - In which way could this linear array swap be optimized away?

Comment: @ChristianRau The unique_ptr<size_t[]> is very similar to a vector - except that it has less overhead, which I assume the OP wanted to achieve. I am not entirely sure *how* my icc optimized the swap away (although I assume, that it coalesced the writes in the one array into with the move to the other array), but it most definitely did :)

Comment: In fact I was totally unable to even reproduce the problem in the beginning: With optimizations the array version of the OP even ran ~15% faster than the vector version!

Comment: *"The `unique_ptr<size_t[]>` is very similar to a vector - except that it has less overhead"* - And what would that overhead be? Is it just the overhead of swapping/moving the additional two pointers the `std::vector` would need that you're after or is there some more overhead you think a `std::vector` would bring?

Comment: Since this function is intended for very small input, I assume the minor improvements due to simpler construction and destruction seem to matter. However, this is not just an out-of-the-blue claim, I measured a speedup by changing a single-vector solution to this one. (I guess it is also possible that the optimizer just works better with this slightly simpler version.)

Comment: I'm not saying it's completely irrelevant, I just wasn't sure what it is exactly what you meant with overhead (but I know now).

Comment: @ChristianRau: The overhead of using a vector is that resizing one forces it to default-construct each element. A new[]ed array of POD type contains whatever random junk happened to be in the memory. If you intend to overwrite the array contents anyway the vector is slower.

Comment: @ZanLynx Yeah, indeed. Forgot about that, too.